# SystemVerilog - How to get an indexed value from an unpacked array?

Tags: arrays, indexing

I'm pretty new to SystemVerilog and find myself in need of getting a byte value from an unpacked array (at least I presume that's what it is) parameter, with the index being the lower 4-bits of a memory address.

So, the parameter is as follows:

`parameter byte BANK[16] = '{8'h09,8'h03,8'h47,8'h50,8'h55,8'h00,8'hFF,8'hFF,8'hFF,8'hFF,8'hFF,8'hFF,8'hFF,8'hFF,8'hFF,8'hFF};  // The data to return`

This is simply an array of 16 bytes.

I need to return one of those bytes from that parameter array, based on the lowest 4-bits of a reg - `addr_hold[7:0]`.

This is what I've tried:

```
returnData[7:0] <= BANK[addr_hold[3:0]];    // Return the appropriate value
```

The idea being that addr_hold[3:0] will be a value between 0-15, so should be a valid index to return a byte value from BANK, but my logic is clearly out somehow as I'm getting this error:

`Error (10687): SystemVerilog error: indexing addr_hold returns an aggregate value`

I've tried every permutation I can think of, but no luck so far.  If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems I'd made a stupid mistake on the declaration for addr_hold.  I'd written:

`reg addr_hold[7:0];`

when it should be:

`reg [7:0] addr_hold;`

Seems to work just fine now.